# problems with input from getchar(), incorrect values saved to variables

Tags: c, pointers, getchar

I'm trying to write a function where it reads in an integer input and saves it to a pointer. the intial value stored at that pointer is 0. When I use getchar in the code below, it doesn't change stored in the pointer to that value from the input. please help!

(This is just a snippet of the code, the function has been correctly defined earlier. )

```
{
    
    
   
    int count_newline_chars = 0; // counts the number of new line chars
    int input_first_line = 0;

    while (count_newline_chars <=0)
    {
        input_first_line = getchar(); 
        if (input_first_line == '\n')
        {
            if (ciphertext)
            {
                *ciphertext = input_first_line;
            }
            break;
        }
        count_newline_chars +=1;
        
        
    }
   
   

}
```

Comment: If I understand the question, you're wondering why `ciphertext` contains an unexpected value after this code is executed? Have you confirmed whether `input_first_line` contains the value you expect?

Comment: yes! actually, input_first_line also has an incorrect value, it gives me the same wrong value

Comment: In that case, I don't think the question has anything to do with pointers. What is the value of `input_first_line`?

Comment: If *ciphertext changes at all, I would expect the above code just to write a newline into it. While `'\n'` is indeed an integer, I suspect you are actually trying to do something different, but more context is needed.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a [mcve] and details of your input and what you expect versus what you're seeing.

Comment: getchar() reads one character at a time and returns the ascii for it. So if you input 1234 then it reads and returns 49,50,51,52 and 10 (for \n). Why not use a scanf("%d", ciphertext)? with you code snippet, given input 1234, it reads and returns 49, increments count_newline_chars and then bail out from the loop as while (count_newline_chars <=0) does not satisfy. So ciphertext will be 0.